# Unable to instantiate chaincode for balance-transfer app

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I tried to follow the steps [here](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/release-1.3/balance-transfer) to instantiate chaincode. Note that I am using NodeJs (and have omitted my actual token below):

```
curl -s -X POST \
  http://localhost:4000/channels/mychannel/chaincodes \
  -H "authorization: Bearer <put JSON Web Token here>" \
  -H "content-type: application/json" \
  -d '{
    "chaincodeName":"mycc",
    "chaincodeVersion":"v0",
    "chaincodeType": "node",
    "args":["a","100","b","200"]
}'
```

but I get this error in the window running `node app`:

```
[2018-11-15 00:46:54.627] [INFO] instantiate-chaincode - instantiate proposal was good
[2018-11-15 00:46:54.628] [ERROR] instantiate-chaincode - instantiate proposal was bad
[2018-11-15 00:46:54.628] [DEBUG] instantiate-chaincode - Failed to send Proposal and receive all good ProposalResponse
[2018-11-15 00:46:54.628] [ERROR] instantiate-chaincode - Failed to instantiate. cause:Failed to send Proposal and receive all good ProposalResponse
(node:73116) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 7): Error: Failed to instantiate. cause:Failed to send Proposal and receive all good ProposalResponse
```

I have pasted full log [here](https://gist.github.com/siddjain/87aa01c4c3aba61ea56331bb2b53315b). Can anyone help me how to fix this? I followed all the steps before in the [link](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/release-1.3/balance-transfer) and had no trouble:

- enrolling user Jim
- creating the channel
- joining peers in Org1 to the channel
- installing the chaincode on peers in Org1

Further I can see a container by the name `dev-peer0.org1.example.com-mycc-v0` which together with the debug log suggests the chaincode was instantiated on peer0 but why is it not getting instantiated on peer1?

What is the meaning of these ports in [docker-compose.yaml](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release-1.3/balance-transfer/artifacts/docker-compose.yaml)?

```
peer0.org1.example.com:
    container_name: peer0.org1.example.com
    ports:
      - 7051:7051
      - 7053:7053


  peer1.org1.example.com:
    container_name: peer1.org1.example.com
    ports:
      - 7056:7051
      - 7058:7053
```

Comment: Have you removed all the previously running Containers ?

Comment: yes I did......

Comment: related: https://lists.hyperledger.org/g/fabric/message/3545

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried it again today with the modification that I specified the peer like below:

```
curl -s -X POST \
  http://localhost:4000/channels/mychannel/chaincodes \
  -H "authorization: Bearer <put JSON Web Token here>" \
  -H "content-type: application/json" \
  -d '{
    "peers": ["peer1.org1.example.com"],
    "chaincodeName":"mycc",
    "chaincodeVersion":"v0",
    "chaincodeType": "node",
    "args":["a","100","b","200"]
}'
```

and this time it succeeded:

```
{"success":true,"message":"Successfully instantiate chaincode in organization Org1 to the channel 'mychannel'"}
```

in node app terminal:

```
[2018-11-15 22:12:26.463] [INFO] instantiate-chaincode - The chaincode instantiate transaction has been committed on peer localhost:7051
[2018-11-15 22:12:26.463] [INFO] instantiate-chaincode - Transaction 979eeb030e6adf9689f39163192fbb9bcba00e6942ef4d1ea6de10d982d234fe has status of VALID in blocl 1
[2018-11-15 22:12:26.464] [INFO] instantiate-chaincode - The chaincode instantiate transaction was valid.
[2018-11-15 22:12:26.464] [DEBUG] instantiate-chaincode - ------->>> R E S P O N S E : ["The chaincode instantiate transaction was valid.",{"status":"SUCCESS","info":""}]
[2018-11-15 22:12:26.465] [INFO] instantiate-chaincode - Successfully sent transaction to the orderer.
[2018-11-15 22:12:26.467] [DEBUG] instantiate-chaincode - Event results for event hub :localhost:7051
[2018-11-15 22:12:26.468] [DEBUG] instantiate-chaincode - The chaincode instantiate transaction was valid.
[2018-11-15 22:12:26.468] [INFO] instantiate-chaincode - Successfully instantiate chaincode in organization Org1 to the channel 'mychannel'
```

I have no idea why it failed yesterday and succeeded today.

Also when I initially made the `curl` request today it failed because the JWT token had expired. To refresh the token I made a request to the `/users` endpoint just like I did to enroll the user yesterday (except this time the user was already enrolled)

```
curl -s -X POST http://localhost:4000/users -H "content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d 'username=Jim&orgName=Org1'
```

below shows the containers:

```
$ docker ps --format '{{.Names}}'
dev-peer1.org1.example.com-mycc-v0
dev-peer0.org1.example.com-mycc-v0
peer1.org2.example.com
peer0.org2.example.com
peer0.org1.example.com
peer1.org1.example.com
ca_peerOrg1
ca_peerOrg2
orderer.example.com
```

and logs from the container in which the chaincode is instantiated:
    $ docker logs -f dev-peer1.org1.example.com-mycc-v0

```
> example_cc@1.0.0 start /usr/local/src
> node example_cc.js "--peer.address" "peer1.org1.example.com:7052"

E1115 22:12:23.956612869      17 ssl_transport_security.cc:238] Could not get common name of subject from certificate.
========= example_cc Init =========
{ fcn: 'node', params: [ 'a', '100', 'b', '200' ] }
```